# jQuery changePage to another local file

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is my my sample jQuery code

```
$("#listitem").swipeleft(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#page1", { transition: "slide", reverse: true });
}); // This works
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    // document.location.href = "test/test.html";  <- this will work
    $.mobile.changePage( "../about.html", { transition: "slideup"} );
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; // some sugeest 
}); // This fails
```

The first one works with redirection to anther element in the same page(#page1)
The second one fails with redirection to anther webpage(about.html) with an error "Error Loading Page". 
What is even weird is that if I transfer html files into a server, the redirect will fail, but the error still pops up. I noticed there was some previous problem with older verson, but since I get the JQM 1.3.2 and JQuery 1.9.1(which are latest version), I cannot solve this problem.
I want to redirect to another page with some animation, and this haunts me for a few days, so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you loading pages off of the local file system? You'll have issues if you're trying to dynamically load content via a `file://` uri.

Answer (score 0):

About.html is in the same level as actual page? you could try removing the ../

Also I would recommend having all the pages at a root level

Comment: Yes, the relative directory should be fine for these.
So if I have "document.location.href = "../about.html";", it redirects fine. But for some reason the changePage just failed.
But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, about.html does use jQuery syntax. I also tried a simple page with some plain text. But the redirection just does not work..

Comment: Have you tried triggering the transition **$.mobile.changePage** from a button event. I have working that way. If it works maybe will be a clue of the swipe event. Also there is any error in the Console, use Chrome Developer Tools